# Java For Loop overwriting previous elements

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the below code containing a for loop to add objects to an array. To my logic I should be able to have 3 objects in the array (maxCountries = 3), but when I go through and add the three objects the for loop overwrites the previously entered values so I only get one object in the array and the other 2 spaces are null.

```
public void addCountryNorth()

{
    if (countrySpaceNorth == maxCountries)
    {
        System.out.println("There are three countries already.");
    }
    else if (countrySpaceNorth < maxCountries)
    {
        System.out.println("Add a new country.");
        int counter = 0;
        do
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("That country already exists.");
            }
            System.out.println("Name: ");
            name = console.next();
            counter++;
        }
        while(countryNameCheck(name) != 0);
        System.out.println("Hemisphere: ");
        hemisphere = console.next();
        System.out.println("GDP: ");
        gdp = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Population: ");
        population = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Life Expectancy: ");
        lifeExpectancy = console.nextDOuble();
        System.out.println("CO2 Emmissions: ");
        co2Emmissions = console.nextDouble();
        countrySpaceNorth++;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxCountries; i++)
        {
            if (country[i] == null)
            {
                country[i] = new Country (name, hemisphere, gdp, population, lifeExpectancy, co2Emmissions);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCountries; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(country[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you think the `break` statement in your loop does? Your for loop is terminated by the `break` statement after the first country is added.

Comment: also: what is this supposed to do? if (counter > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("That country already exists.");
            }

Comment: @maloomeister I suppose the break is used to enter the new country only once. Otherwise the new country would fill all the null position in country

Comment: It _seems_ that you are reading these values from some input (user input? `console.next`?). If yes, what you'll want to do is to move that code into the for loop, so that _for each_ possible array entry you read the values, and _then_ write them into the array.

Comment: I am reading the values from user input. What would that look like if I moved it into the for loop? I think I understand how to move the user input parts, but not how to assign them to the 3 objects I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Since we couldn't execute your code is not very clear what the problem could be, in the meantime I suggest you some changes:

- is a better idea to increment `countrySpaceNorth` once you actually add the new country to `courtry`
- `couter` seems to be useless

```
public void addCountryNorth()
{
    if (countrySpaceNorth == maxCountries)
    {
        System.out.println("There are three countries already.");
    }
    else if (countrySpaceNorth < maxCountries)
    {
        System.out.println("Add a new country.");
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Name: ");
            name = console.next();
        }
        while(countryNameCheck(name) != 0);
        System.out.println("Hemisphere: ");
        hemisphere = console.next();
        System.out.println("GDP: ");
        gdp = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Population: ");
        population = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Life Expectancy: ");
        lifeExpectancy = console.nextDOuble();
        System.out.println("CO2 Emmissions: ");
        co2Emmissions = console.nextDouble();

        for (int i = 0; i < maxCountries; i++)
        {
            if (country[i] == null)
            {
                country[i] = new Country (name, hemisphere, gdp, population, lifeExpectancy, co2Emmissions);
                countrySpaceNorth++;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCountries; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(country[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, when I tried this code it threw a null pointer exception in the first for loop. Any ideas? Sorry I'm really new to Java. Thanks for your advice so far!

Comment: @JavaStudent Don't worry. Can you please post some additional information about the exception?
I don't know all your code, but it is possible that `country` doesn't have the index you're trying to access?

Comment: It says "Cannot load from object array because "this.country" is null". It breaks at the line 'if (country[i]  == null). So I'm guessing the object hasn't been placed in the array?

Comment: @JavaStudent As I said before, I'm pretty sure that `country` is not initialized and so trying to verify if one of it's own element is null thrown an exception
Probably, if you tried to write `if(country == null)` the condition would be verified. So, you have to initialize `country` before trying to work with its elements

Comment: So adding Country[] country = new Country[maxCountries]; to the start of the method?

Comment: @JavaStudent If the array has not been initialized as you wrote it anywhere else yes.
Seems strange to me tho that before, when you posted the question, it didn't thrown this exception

Answer (score 0):

I'd try encapsulating a lot of the functionality into methods to make digesting the program easier.

I refactored the code a fair amount to extract everything away from your method to individual methods/functions and it looks like your logic becomes very confused from the moment you introduce the do-while loop. Try instead to use a for-loop.. here's an example of a working application that I've hacked together and I think follows your intentions:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {

    private static int countrySpaceNorth;
    private static final int MAX_COUNTRIES = 3;
    private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Country[] countryArray = new Country[MAX_COUNTRIES];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addCountryNorth();
        addCountryNorth();
        addCountryNorth();

    }

    public static void addCountryNorth() {
        if (countrySpaceNorth == MAX_COUNTRIES) {
            System.out.println("There are three countries already.");
        } else if (countrySpaceNorth < MAX_COUNTRIES) {

            String countryName = getCountryName();

            String hemisphere = hemisphere();
            double gdp = gdp();
            int population = population();
            double lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy();
            double co2Emissions = co2Emissions();

            countrySpaceNorth++;
            addCountryToFirstEmptySlotInArray(countryName, hemisphere, gdp, population, lifeExpectancy, co2Emissions);
            System.out.println(); // print blank line after each country added.

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(countryArray));
        }
    }

    private static void addCountryToFirstEmptySlotInArray(String countryName, String hemisphere, double gdp, int population, double lifeExpectancy, double co2Emmissions) {
        if (countryArray != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<MAX_COUNTRIES; i++) {
                if (countryArray[i]==null) {
                    countryArray[i] = new Country(countryName, hemisphere, gdp, population, lifeExpectancy, co2Emmissions);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getCountryName() {
        System.out.println("Add a new country.");
        boolean countryNameAlreadyExists = false;
        String countryName = "";
        do {
            if (countryNameAlreadyExists) {
                System.out.println("That country already exists.");
            }
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            countryName = console.next();
            countryNameAlreadyExists = true;
        } while (countryNameCount(countryName) != 0);
        return countryName;
    }

    private static double co2Emissions() {
        System.out.print("CO2 Emmissions: ");
        double co2Emmissions = console.nextDouble();
        return co2Emmissions;
    }

    private static double lifeExpectancy() {
        System.out.print("Life Expectancy: ");
        double lifeExpectany = console.nextDouble();
        return lifeExpectany;
    }

    private static int population() {
        System.out.print("Population: ");
        int population = console.nextInt();
        return population;
    }

    private static double gdp() {
        System.out.print("GDP: ");
        double gdp = console.nextDouble();
        return gdp;
    }

    private static String hemisphere() {
        System.out.print("Hemisphere: ");
        String hemisphere = console.next();
        return hemisphere;
    }

    private static long countryNameCount(String name) {
        if (countryArray.length > 0) {
            return Arrays.stream(countryArray).filter(countryName -> countryName!=null && countryName.equals(name)).count();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

class Country {

    private final String name;
    private final String hemisphere;
    private final double gdp;
    private final int population;
    private final double lifeExpectancy;
    private final double co2Emmissions;

    public Country(String name, String hemisphere, double gdp, int population, double lifeExpectancy, double co2Emmissions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hemisphere = hemisphere;
        this.gdp = gdp;
        this.population = population;
        this.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
        this.co2Emmissions = co2Emmissions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", hemisphere='" + hemisphere + '\'' +
                ", gdp=" + gdp +
                ", population=" + population +
                ", lifeExpectancy=" + lifeExpectancy +
                ", co2Emmissions=" + co2Emmissions +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Add a new country.
Name: France
Hemisphere: 123
GDP: 123
Population: 123
Life Expectancy: 123
CO2 Emmissions: 123

[Country{name='France', hemisphere='123', gdp=123.0, population=123, lifeExpectancy=123.0, co2Emmissions=123.0}, null, null]
Add a new country.
Name: UK
Hemisphere: North
GDP: 123
Population: 123
Life Expectancy: 123
CO2 Emmissions: 123

[Country{name='France', hemisphere='123', gdp=123.0, population=123, lifeExpectancy=123.0, co2Emmissions=123.0}, Country{name='UK', hemisphere='North', gdp=123.0, population=123, lifeExpectancy=123.0, co2Emmissions=123.0}, null]
Add a new country.
Name: Germany
Hemisphere: North
GDP: 123
Population: 123
Life Expectancy: 123
CO2 Emmissions: 123

[Country{name='France', hemisphere='123', gdp=123.0, population=123, lifeExpectancy=123.0, co2Emmissions=123.0}, Country{name='UK', hemisphere='North', gdp=123.0, population=123, lifeExpectancy=123.0, co2Emmissions=123.0}, Country{name='Germany', hemisphere='North', gdp=123.0, population=123, lifeExpectancy=123.0, co2Emmissions=123.0}]
```

I have tested this accepts one country, entry via the debugger. There may be some other bugs in the code so please don't consider this a complete solution.

I understood (rightly/wrongly) from your implementation you wanted to add countries to the countryArray only if they didn't already exist. You're method for checking this was to check whether a count of the country name in the array was != 0. This is not a bad way to do it but there are better ways. This also confuses things heavily because you attempt to add 3 countries, but then only add the country properties for one (after the do-while loop finishes).

When you get further down to your first for-loop, you end up with only one country because the do-while loop over-writes `name = console.next();` each time... you're not creating 3 countries here (as indicated is the intention in the code output & question).

Comment: I do want to add 3 countries. Each with individual name, hemisphere, gdp, population, lifeExpectancy and co2Emmissions values. I want to be able to do it one at a time, not all three at once like your code above does it. How would I add the additional names in the above code?

Comment: It seems to break down at the "Add a new Country" line. Any ideas?